# iOS8 change height of dynamic cell "now", re internal cell content

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios-autolayout

Here's a dynamic cell

[image]

Note - in the example, the text is not data driven. It's just some text local to the cell (consider, say, a help text). At runtime, change the .text of the UILabel from one word to many lines, using a button actually inside the cell. iOS perectly resizes the cell and table....

... but **only when the cell is scrolled offscreen, and then on again**.

How to alert the table view to recalculate everything "now" ?

---

*(Please note, this question ONLY in the case of iOS8+, Xcode7+, autolayout for dynamic cell heights.)*

Comment: emm, I guess you should somehow trig autolayout when you assigning new text to label and internal magic does rest. Or there is something not so straightforward?

Comment: I added explanation why you should not - ever - change the content from the cell, and also added the solution about how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm presuming you're not setting the `text` property of the `UILabel` inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` but rather somewhere else (or doing it asynchronously). If that's the case, I wouldn't update the UI there. Rather, I'd update the model backing the table and then call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`. That will let `cellForRowAtIndexPath` call again, but unlike reloading the whole table, this will gracefully keep the `contentOffset` of the tableview right where it is.

I know this all sounds unnecessarily complicated, but the bottom line is that you don't own this view, the table view does. It has to do all sorts of stuff above and beyond updating the cell. I.e., if the cell grew, figure out which cells scrolled out of view and dequeue them. If the cell shrunk, figure out which cells scrolled into view as a result.

It's a surprisingly complex dance. You can try calling `setNeedsLayout` on the cell, but I wouldn't expect that to work (and even if it does, it is a fragile approach). The table view is responsible for managing its cells, so if you really should just update model and reload that one cell.

Comment: Got it, it makes perfect sense. You *just can't* have a cell do anything to itself, really.  After all, it's an entity that may or may not be onscreen, could be formed or re-formed at any time from the prototypes, etc.  (Re setNeedsLayout, it seems to do nothing!)

Comment: In full disclosure, there are times that people are updating a cell directly, asynchronously. (The most common example includes all of those various `UIImageView` categories for asynchronous image loading.) But those only work if the cell height doesn't change. And architecturally, it's the wrong approach. It's much better to update the model and then call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`.

Answer (score 2):

**Changing height**

So basically, there are two ways to do:

The first one is to actually reload the cell (not the tableview). Reloading will call new heightForRow (don't forget to purge cache, if you are caching the sizes), which will return proper new height:

```
 let indexPaths = [NSIndexPath(forRow: ~the rows in question~, inSection: 0)]
 self.table.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
```

(Note however that this often involves reloading more than one row; notably if you select/deselect, you have to reload all rows changed.)

If however you ONLY want to change the size of the cell and the content per se, and did not really change the data content ... so for example:

- you clicked some button and you assigned new local text in the cell to outlets (perhaps a help text):
- you changed only the LAYOUT of the cell.  for example, you made a font larger, or changed the margin of a block of text so that the height of a block of text changed, so indeed the height of the overall cell changed:

In that case instead of reloading, just call the following, which forces the tableview to basically do all animations, and for that it needs new heights, so it requests it:

```
 self.table.beginUpdates()
 self.table.endUpdates()
```

**The true solution**

I see what your problem is. You are trying to change the height of the cell from the actual cell - but you will not succeed in that -> and you should not. See, the cell is view, and view should not have any idea about its data whatsoever - view is what presents. If you need any changes, you should inform your controller to do so. To do that, you can use notifications, but preferably protocols / delegates.

So at first you create protocol in your cell, which will be used to inform the controller, that there is a change:

```
 protocol MyCellDelegate {

    func buttonTappedForCell(cell : UITableViewCell)
 }
```

Now, you need to conform to that protocol in your view controller that contains table:

```
 class MyClassWithTableView : MyCellDelegate
```

Lastly, you need to declare delegate in the cell:

```
 class MyCell {
     var delegate : MyCellDelegate
 }
```

And assign it in the configuration of the cell, which you probably have in the view controller:

```
 cell.delegate = self
```

This is the basic setup for all the delegates / protocols really, and now, when you click on your button, you can forward the action to your controller:

```
 @IBAction myButtonTouchUpInside() {

     self.delegate.buttonTappedForCell(self)
 }
```

After doing all that, proceed as in part 1. That is to say, either `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` or a `beginUpdates` / `endUpdates` pair as explained above.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I added the solution to your other problem, as I finally understood what you are actually trying to do :)

Comment: Hi Jiri !  I realised that what you explained about the difference between `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` versus a `beginUpdates` / `endUpdates` pair is a critical thing.  I actually went ahead and boldly edited your answer to expand on this point.  See if you like it ....

Comment: BTW I've just discovered `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` . . . it's intriguing that nobody mentioned it in this context.  It performs a similar role to `'reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`

Comment: Here is why it should not be like that :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609206/setneedslayout-vs-setneedsupdateconstraints-and-layoutifneeded-vs-updateconstra

Comment: Jiri, thanks for the vast amount of useful info, which I am sure will also be incredibly useful for future googlers. I clicked over a token bounty as a token of my appreciation, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

did you try calling reloadRowsAtIndexPaths on the cell index? it's supposed to animate to the new size, if the constraints are setup correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `self.tableView.reloadData()` just **AFTER** you made the cell's label's text change.

It will force the `tableView` to redraw the cell's. That's what happened when you scroll, the cell is being `reused`, and redrawn when it comes back again.

EDIT:

If you can't or won't do a reloadData on your tableView, you can use:

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(row:0 section:0)] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Actually if your content is static and the kind of "help" form, a  simple reloadData() will be lighting fast

Comment: @JoeBlow Not at all, reloadRowsAtIndexPaths will only reload the array of rows you are providing. If you provide an array with only one row, it will reload only this one. There is no other way to make it more efficient

Comment: BTW, `beingUpdates` and `endUpdates` is only necessary if you're doing multiple updates that you want to perform together. If doing single `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`, the `begin`/`endUpdates` is not necessary.

Comment: However @Rob I realised that, if I'm not mistaken, you can indeed call a `beginUpdates` / `endUpdates` pair if you just changed the layout (imagine say tripling the point size of the font in a slab of text, so that the cell is now much longer).  In contrast if (as asked in my question) you are essentially changing the model data (as one, we now know, should), one would have to indeed reload.  Sounds about right I think........(I hope :) )

Comment: @JoeBlow - Yes, as the docs say "You can also use [`beginUpdates`] followed by the `endUpdates` method to animate the change in the row heights without reloading the cell." But to call `beginUpdates`, then reload a cell, and then call `endUpdates` is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know your code but did you really execute your ui changes on the main thread. Same problem happened to me and was solved with putting the exectuion on the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
        [...]
    }
```

Comment: Hi Philipp, it's a good point but not my particular problem, I'm afraid!